# php script tests fine but executes differently

Tags: php

The variable sessionId is passed via URL. With an html/php script it tested fine.  Suppose the URL had http://xxxx?sessionId=Sam, the variable fileId was SamM.wav.  But when the exact script was put in the server, the saved file is M.wav instead of SamM.wav - what am I missing? Below is the code:
Update: 
PHP versions:
PHP 5.4
PHP 5.5.22

```
    <?php
        $Id =   $_GET["sessionId"]  ;
        $fileId = "$Id" . "M.wav";      


        $fp = fopen( "$fileId", 'wb' );
        fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS[ 'HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA' ] );
        fclose( $fp );
    ?>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Well i have this on my private server and it works fine:

```
<?php
ini_set("display_errors", true);
error_reporting(E_ALL);


$id = $_GET["sessionId"];
$fileId = $id . "M.wav";

$fp = fopen( "./writetest/" . $fileId, 'wb' );

if(is_resource($fp) === true) {
     fwrite( $fp, 'test');
     fclose( $fp );
} else {
    echo "nope";
}
?>
```

my ls shows:

```
[root@servername]# ls -l writetest/
total 4
-rw-r--r--. 1 **** **** 4 Mar 25 21:11 testM.wav
```

Comment: I tried again on 1and1.com - still it is "M.wav" - if it is a server issue, what server in the USA will fix this?

Comment: In fwrite( $fp, 'test'), should "test" be $fileId instead - I am unsure how you put test in there and the created filename became testM.wav?

Comment: the test in fwrite() is only the content of the file for testing (in my case)

Comment: With your error reporting, even if it is running on a server, you get to see them - where or how?  What do I need to do if I want to create a log of errors?

Comment: What do you mean with "running on a server"? Do you mean running from the command line? Like "php index.php?sessionId=Sam" ? Or do you mean it is running on the server through Apache

Comment: Through Apache using a browser.

Comment: Ok, don't know your server set-up but by default the apache logs are in the "/var/log/apache2" or "/var/log/httpd" folder on your server. The error_reporting(E_ALL) will echo any PHP error in your browser.

Comment: I think that the problem is the sessionId from frond end is not passed to the backend php script - how can the front end value passed to the backend php script?

Comment: Actually from front end to JavaScropt (where php script is invoked) - so I think that the sessionId needs to be passed to JS and then to PHP - this is the issue in my case?

Answer (score 0):

Think it has to be:

```
<?php
    $id = $_GET["sessionId"];
    $fileId = $id . "M.wav";      

    $fp = fopen( $fileId, 'wb' );
    fwrite( $fp, $GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA'] );
    fclose( $fp );
?>
```

And i don't know which version of PHP you are running but "$GLOBALS['HTTP_RAW_POST_DATA']" is deprecated from version "5.6.0".

see for more information: http://php.net/manual/en/reserved.variables.httprawpostdata.php

And it is not: http://xxxx?sessionId=Sam but http://xxxx/?sessionId=Sam
(i know most browsers will redirect you but some won't)

Comment: PHP versions:
PHP 5.4
PHP 5.5.22

Comment: Just to make sure, I copied your code and ran it on 1and1 server. It still "M.wav" and not "SamM.wav"?  As for the URL, it is like  "http:// xxxx/xxx.php?sessionId=Sam" - what might be the fix?